# Python, listing images with glob, empty list when using variables

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I'm trying to get a list of images in a directory using glob

I have two methods, the first one works, but the second does not

```
from pathlib import Path
jpgs = list(Path('X:\\path\\to\\directory').rglob("*.[jJ][pP][gG]"))
```

The second has the directory started as a string in the `image_path`

```
image_path = 'X:\\path\\to\\directory'
jpgs = list(Path(image_path).rglob("*.[jJ][pP][gG]"))
```

I do not understand why the second returns an empty list, any ideas?

Comment: I tested you on jupyter notebook and both ran without any problems.Probably a problem with the IDE

Comment: I ended up using os.path.join() to generate the paths rather than string manipulation, solved whatever the issue was